# Using Selenium with Java to Automate, how to I make an object oriented part of a script "actionable?"

Tags: java, selenium

I have automated a new customer form for work, but there are a lot of options and based on how questions are answered , different fields need to be filled out. Rather than just make a copy of the code and make a different script for each option, I'd like to do this by passing values to a class that determines what options are chosen based on what is passed in. I'm trying to figure most of this out myself and I'm somewhat of a n00b, but if someone can get me past the first hurdle, I'd like to tackle the rest of the hurdles myself.

So I want to start by just doing one line of the script this way, and eventually I will do more. Up front, it is going to seem like a lot of code just to do this, but here is the line:

`driver.findElement(By.id("OrganizationName")).sendKeys("The Rolling Stones");`

Here is what I have so far:

```
ncformPage1 skifootz = new ncformPage1("Rolling Stones");
skifootz.getOrgname();
```

That is the part that is in the script. Here is the class I wrote:

```
public class ncformPage1 {
    private String orgName;
    public ncformPage1(String on) {
        orgName = on;
    }

    public String getOrgname() { return "driver.findElement(By.id(\"OrganizationName\")).sendKeys(\""
    + orgName + "\");";
    }
}
```

So when I run this, it goes right past that organizationName element and leaves it blank, does all the other elements, and then fails because organization name is a required field. So I added this bit of code here to see what it prints out to the console:

`System.out.println( skifootz.getOrgname());`

Sure enough, it prints out

`driver.findElement(By.id("OrganizationName")).sendKeys("Rolling Stones");`

Which is exactly what I want returned. (I think the last semicolon is extraneous in this case, but at least it returned what I wanted!) But it doesn't execute that. I've tried all kinds of stuff to get it to execute, such as removing driver from what is returned and appending it here instead:

`driver.skifootz.getOrgname();`

but that gives me skifootz cannot be resolved or is not a field. I tried this:

```
String a = skifootz.getOrgname();
driver.a();
```

But that just made a get underlined in red saying method a() is undefined for the type Webdriver. So then I changed String a to Webdriver a:

```
WebDriver a = skifootz.getOrgname();
driver.a();
```

But now skifootz.getOrgname(); is underlined saying "type mismatch: cannot convert from String to WebDriver." I've been messing around with it for a few days now, and I haven't gotten any closer. Maybe this is an easy solution, but if I can just get this part working then perhaps I can move on to the next phase? This n00b thanks everyone in advance for any help anyone can give.

Answer (score 0):

The method is returning a String type and you expect it to act like a driver object. That part is incorrect.

I think you can write methods to be more like

```
public WebElement getOrgname(WebDriver driver, String OrganizationName) { 
    return driver.findElement(By.id(OrganizationName));
}

WebElement a = skifootz.getOrgname(driver);
a.sendKeys("Rolling Stones");
```

OR

```
public void TypeText(WebDriver driver, String OrganizationName, String TextToType) { 
    driver.findElement(By.id(OrganizationName)).sendKeys(TextToType);;
}
```

in your context this should probably work.

```
ncformPage1 skifootz = new ncformPage1();
skifootz.getOrgname(skifootz.driver, "OrganizationName");
skifootz.sendKeys("Rolling Stones");


public class ncformPage1 {
    private String orgName;
    public WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  // I'm assuming this part.
    public ncformPage1(String on) {
        orgName = on;
   }

    public WebElement getOrgname(WebDriver driver, String OrganizationName) { 
        return driver.findElement(By.id(OrganizationName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Naveen! Thank you for your help. I am trying the first one. I put the first part into my ncformpage1 class and the second one into the main selenium script., The only problem is that "skifootz" in "WebElement a = skifootz.getOrgname(driver);" is no longer an instance of the ncformpage1 class, so what role does it play here? This is the last part I think before I can get it to work (I think!) Thanks, Naveen!

Comment: I've updated the answer to fit your context. Please check and make necessary adjustments.

Comment: Hi Naveen! So it accepted your entire ncformPage1 class. But for the part that calls the method, it underlines the driver part of this: skifootz.getOrgname(skifootz.driver, "OrganizationName"); and says "The field ncformPage1.driver is not visible" and also "sendKeys" in the last line, which says "The method sendKeys(String) is undefined for the type ncformPage1"

Comment: My bad. Declared private WebDriver to  public WebDriver. Check it now.

Comment: I feel like we're getting closer.. Now, in the line "ncformPage1 skifootz = new ncformPage1();" it has the new ncformPage1() part of  "ncformPage1 skifootz = new ncformPage1();" underlined in red: "The constructor ncformPage1() is undefined" which is weird since I didn't change the name, spelling ,or the capitalization. Also, sendKeys is still underlined with the same message. Thanks for your continued help, Naveen!